# $exception Unable to evaluate the expression. Operation not supported. Unknown error: 0x80040914

Tags: sql, vb.net, exception

Here's my code and the error is with cmd.
Please help. whats wrong with the code?

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Module Module1
    Public conn As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand
    Public dr As MySqlDataReader
    Public sql As String

    Public Sub connect()

        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = conn

        conn.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I see no connection string of the `conn` object.

Comment: Don't declare database objects at the Module level. Declare them in the method where they are used so the can be disposed with `Using...End Using` blocks.

Comment: The error message suggests that there is an issue with your SQL but you haven't actually shown us that.

Comment: Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient


Module Module1
    Public conn As MySqlConnection
    Public ds As New DataSet
    Public cm As MySqlCommand
    Public dr As MySqlDataReader

    Sub Connection()
        conn = New MySqlConnection
        With conn
            .ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root; port = 3306; password = caching_sha2_password; database = logindata"

        End With
    End Sub

End Module

Comment: Here's the MySql data                  Table: logininfo
Columns:
ID int AI PK 
Username varchar(45) 
Password varchar(45)